# How to make a C++ map::swap thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to swap out a std::map to update some configuration.  This occurs in one thread.

In another thread, I need to read in the values from that map (just one consumer thread, for now).

In the producer thread, I currently have (pseudo-code):

```
pthread_mutex lock;
std::map<int, char> current_config;
std::map<int, char> new_config;
...
<Read into new config>
ScopeLock(lock);
current_config.swap(new_config);
```

In the consumer thread, I call an accessor in the producer thread that does the following:

```
ScopeLock(lock)
return current_config;
```

This seems like it would prevent a consumer from accessing the map during the swap, but I wonder what will happen if a consumer is using the map, and then the producer needs to swap the maps.

Is this thread safe?

I suppose I could do a lock in both threads, but I was trying to avoid requiring the consumer to use a lock.

Comment: Your consumer doesn't do any lookups. It appears like all it does is return a reference or copy to the map, then the callee does the lookup. If it's a copy, then it's inefficient but thread safe. If it's a reference, then it's not thread safe (the scoped lock is released at the return, before the callee can do a lookup).

Comment: The lock doesn't protect anything, if not all access comes through there. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your accessor returns by  reference, the code is not safe, because the consumer gets the reference, the lock is released, but your producer might do another swap.

If the accessor returns by value, then your code COULD be safe, because you set the lock and return a copy and then the lock is removed.

I say "COULD" because your protection is not sufficient:  I suppose your producer is not only swapping the maps, but that it's also initializing, filling it and updateing them. So you would need to set the lock for each and every producer function that modifies the map in any way.  Otherwhise your consumer could read the map, thinking it's safe, while other pieces of code alter the existing places.

In addition working with the copy means that your consumer could use obsolete data, making the processing not so concurrent as it could be.

An alternative could be that producer and consumer use a shared map, embedded in an object designed to embed a thread safe access to the map by both producer and consumer.

Comment: So what I have actually decided on doing is just pulling in the configuration and updating my map in one thread, and use a "version" flag.  In my consumer thread, I am going to add a simple polling mechanism that will read in the configuration and update it's own copy of the map only when an update is detected.  This will prevent the thread safety issues entirely.